# Как получить Array или Объект с месяцами?

Tags: javascript

Самый очевидный вариант это взять и прописать все вручную

```
var months = {
        01: "January",
        02: "February",
        03: "March",
        04: "April",
        05: "May",
        06: "June",
        07: "July",
        08: "August",
        09: "September",
        10: "October",
        11: "November",
        12: "December"
    }
```

Но как можно получить аналогичный объект или массив, не прописывая месяцы вручную, и сделать это на чистом JS без библиотек?

Comment: Для начала надо понять - зачем. какая задача. А потом уже смотреть на то, нужен ли вам такой массив/объект или нет. Потому что в JS по дате можно вытащить его наименование. Но списка там нет

Comment: `new Date('1970-11-01T00:00:00').toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' })`

Answer (score 2):

Вариант через `Array.from` (ES6+), и с использованием `Intl.DateTimeFormat` вместо методов `Date` - просто чтобы показать такую возможность:

```js
const mFrmtr = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(void(0), { month: 'long' }); 
const months = Array.from({ length: 12 }, 
  (v, i) => mFrmtr.format(new Date(0, i)) 
); 

console.log(months);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var months = [], i;
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    months.push(new Date(0,i).toLocaleString({},{month:'long'}));
}
console.log(months);
```

ps. на основе комментария от nörbörnën